# How many football fans were originally travelling to the game?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Football fans were travelling to a game in 32 minibuses. 8 minibuses broke down on the way and the fans from these buses got on the remaining ones; there was an equal number of people in each bus. After that, there were two more fans in every minibus.

Let x denote the number of people in a single bus.

32x=24(x+2)

32x=24x+48

8x=48

x=6

32*6=192

I'm curious to know what logical errors I made as my answer seems to make sense to me, but after viewing the solution it seems like I'm wrong (256).

Comment: you are correct, you can not divide 256 by 24.

Comment: We know that 48 people came from the 8 broken down buses, so there are 6 people per bus to BEGIN with. After the the breaking down of the 8 buses, the remaining 24 had 6 + 2 each. Therefore there are a total of 24 * 8 = 192. I too got your answer with a different approach, however it seems like the solution got 256 from 32 * 8 = 256. I believe the solution is wrong.